# Limiting login tries to protect from BFA's

Tags: php, mysql, brute-force, login-attempts

I have implemented a login system where after 3 unsuccessful tries (using `$_SESSION` variables) a cookie is created on the user's computer which expires in 10 minutes. Now I know this is certainly not sufficient, as they can just delete the cookie. Now, what I want to know is, when I implement a table to capture incorrect logins via IP's & username combos, when does this table get cleared? When the user successfully logs in after the block time has expired?

Let's say this table get populated with a 1000 entries, how do I automatically clear this? What is the structure of the table?

I propose this:
**4 fields:** ID, IP, username (which will be their email address), block_time (time user can log in again)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a record after first unsuccessful login, and remove it after login succeeds.

The second approach would be creating "modified" column, and cleaning it using some php-cron script.

```
INSERT INTO user_logins(user_hash, time) VALUES(?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = now()
```

of course, your primary key would be user_hash.

Comment: That's my plan, though I have never done a complex login system like this.

Comment: I don't think that this would be complicated. You may want to create a hash, based on user IP and maybe username, and add it to the database when login failed, after second login, you would just update the user record, then after successful login, you would delete all records where user_hash = hash($userIp . $userName).